# How do I undo, what multipass did to my networking device

Tags: networking, multipass

I ran the following command trying to be able to access the multipass vms from outside the host computer.

```
multipass launch --network name=enp8s0,mode=auto
```

This is now the output from "multipass networks --format yaml":

```
br-enp8s0:
  - type: bridge
    description: Network bridge with enp8s0
enp8s0:
  - type: ethernet
    description: Ethernet device
lxdbr0:
  - type: bridge
    description: Network bridge
mpbr0:
  - type: bridge
    description: Network bridge for Multipass
```

Now multipass is busted.  I can't create/access any vms.  My host computer still works, but enp8s0 is now a "child" to br-enp8s0.  I would like to delete br-enp8s0 and let enp8s0 communicate directly to the router once again.

Here is the output from ip a:

````
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel master br-enp8s0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether bc:5f:f4:96:02:dd brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: br-enp8s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether e6:55:e5:22:21:3d brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.38/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute br-enp8s0
       valid_lft 85938sec preferred_lft 85938sec
    inet6 fe80::b0f5:2316:4c9:3f29/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: lxdbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:18:91:f2 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.18.84.1/24 scope global lxdbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd42:afc8:d9de:b09a::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
5: mpbr0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:16:3e:cf:bb:61 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.162.239.1/24 scope global mpbr0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fd42:da6c:15b3:7a5a::1/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::216:3eff:fecf:bb61/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever```
````

Answer (score 0):

Turns out all I had to do was to delete the two devices enp8s0 and br-enp8s0 and recreate enp8s0.

This hasn't gotten me any closer to accessing VMs directly from a machine external to the host, but I am back on track.

Comment: "accessing VMs directly from a machine external to the host" - it's called advanced NAT rules on the host system to port forward properly into the VMs from outside the host.  How you do that is entirely dependent on your OS and hwo you manage the firewall on the host.

Comment: @ThomasWard as of late last year, Multipass is supposed to be able to give VMs network addressable IPs and route traffic to and from them, like VMWare etc, so you arent limited to port forwarding.  But it doesn't seem to be very stable doing so, lots of people having issues.